# Angular/Ionic CORS error with Authorization header

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors, http-headers, iis-10

I am building an Ionic app (angular 4) and i want to consume an API which is build with C# on an IIS 10.

When at first did a POST request like that:

```
this.http.post(my_url, my_credentials, { headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  })
});
```

i got a cors **error 404** message:

```
Failed to load https://some_url/api/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

After some research i added on `web.config`

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

and that solved the CORS issues.

After that i retrieve my access token and wanted to use it for others requests
so i made another post request with **authorization header** :

```
this.http.post(my_url, my_body, { headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
  })
});
```

and then i got the same error as previous.

So, to sum up those requests are on the same app. The first request work great but the second no.

What's the extra configuration has to put on the server tou accept the extra Authorization header?

Answer (score 0):

try to add to web.config:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET (..and more Methods that you need.)
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
```

I'm not sure if it will work, but you can give it a try :P

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add proxy.conf.json to redirect your app URL's to your appropriate server URL's. The following article might help:
https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

Answer (score 0):

I use, and works for an asp.net core backend

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
   .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
   .set('Accept', 'application/json')
   .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token); 

this.http.post(my_url, my_credentials, headers)
```

Don't remember if this is valid for http, I think it is only valid foy httpClient